# How to remove the '%7b' character from the URL in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade

My href anchor Tag URL has unwanted characters like '%7B'. How to remove it from the url?

I have added "//" char to remove such characters before the field name like this
`href='//{{$file->awskey}}`'.

Comment: Show more details , what is your full url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the str_replace() function to replace the "%7b" character with an empty string:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/%7babc';
$decodedUrl = str_replace('%7b', '', $url);
```

In this example, $decodedUrl is the URL string with the "%7b" character removed.

Or

To remove the "%7B" character from a URL in a Laravel anchor tag, you can use the urldecode() function

```
<a href="{{ urldecode('//'.$file->awskey) }}">Link</a>
```